# Regular Expression validator for date format DD/MMM/YYYY

Tags: .net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDob" runat="server" MaxLength="100" CssClass="textbox2" size="10"  />
<ajax:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtWEDOB" WatermarkText="DD/MON/YYYY" TargetControlID="txtDob" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rfv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDob" SetFocusOnError="true" 
ValidationExpression="^(3[0-1]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|0[1-9])[\s{1}|\/|-](Jan|JAN|Feb|FEB|Mar|MAR|Apr|APR|May|MAY|Jun|JUN|Jul|JUL|Aug|AUG|Sep|SEP|Oct|OCT|Nov|NOV|Dec|DEC)[\s{1}|\/|-]\d{4}$"  
Display="None" ValidationGroup="search" ErrorMessage="Please enter correct date">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

I am using this regular expression validator for date. It is not giving error for like 12-FEB-2010 or 12 Feb 2010. I strictly want 12/FEB/2010 format. This Regular expressii\on is not working for date like 29/FEB/2010. what changes need to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be very complicated regular expression if you want to validate all the possible cases (like for example 30/FEB).

You will need sub-expression for months with 30 day, you will need a sub-expression for months with 31 day, and the most interesting is Feb and leap years. I don't think that using a regular expression is a good idea here.

[EDIT]

To the question in the comment:

```
^((31(?! (FEB|APR|JUN|SEP|NOV)))|((30|29)(?! FEB))|(29(?= FEB (((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))))|(0?[1-9])|1\d|2[0-8])/(JAN|FEB|MAR|MAY|APR|JUL|JUN|AUG|OCT|SEP|NOV|DEC)/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$
```

Comment: So what changes need to be done in my regular expression which also checks for 30 FEB also

Comment: yes ^((31(?! (FEB|APR|JUN|SEP|NOV)))|((30|29)(?! FEB))|(29(?= FEB (((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))))|(0?[1-9])|1\d|2[0-8]) (JAN|FEB|MAR|MAY|APR|JUL|JUN|AUG|OCT|SEP|NOV|DEC) ((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$ this is the regular expression which work for dates like 30 Feb also. bt its format is DD MMM YYYY. can u please change it into DD/MMM/YYYY format

Comment: sorry like for 29 FEB not 30 FEB

Comment: @user698047 - ^((31(?! (FEB|APR|JUN|SEP|NOV)))|((30|29)(?! FEB))|(29(?= FEB (((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))))|(0?[1-9])|1\d|2[0-8])/(JAN|FEB|MAR|MAY|APR|JUL|JUN|AUG|OCT|SEP|NOV|DEC)/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$

Comment: Its working It must be like ^((31(?!/(FEB|APR|JUN|SEP|NOV)))|((30|29)(?!/FEB))|(29(?=/FEB/(((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))))|(0?[1-9])|1\d|2[0-8])/(JAN|FEB|MAR|MAY|APR|JUL|JUN|AUG|OCT|SEP|NOV|DEC)/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$ Thanks for ur support

Comment: @user698047 - this is exactly what I pasted in my last comment :).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've cut-and-paste this regex from somewhere else?

This part (`[\s{1}|\/|-]`) is where your problem is.  This allows space (\s) and hyphen (-), as well as the / character.

It should instead be `\/`.  So your current regex

```
"^(3[0-1]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|0[1-9])[\s{1}|\/|-](Jan|JAN|Feb|FEB|Mar|MAR|Apr|APR|May|MAY|Jun|JUN|Jul|JUL|Aug|AUG|Sep|SEP|Oct|OCT|Nov|NOV|Dec|DEC)[\s{1}|\/|-]\d{4}$
```

becomes

```
"^(3[0-1]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|0[1-9])\/(Jan|JAN|Feb|FEB|Mar|MAR|Apr|APR|May|MAY|Jun|JUN|Jul|JUL|Aug|AUG|Sep|SEP|Oct|OCT|Nov|NOV|Dec|DEC)\/\d{4}$
```

edit: there was a typo (a missing `(`) in the 'new' regex in this answer which I've fixed.

Be aware that this does **not** resolve any problems regarding the number of days in different months (e.g. 30 Feb).  However I do not find that it matches "311apr}2011" as Hans has posited in the comments - any further comment?

This correctly addresses your question.  I do agree with the comments below that regex are a terrible tool for date validation, but I'm providing an answer rather than trying to give you general advice.

Comment: yes u are correct. i want little more correct. this regular expression is not working like if i enter 29/FEB/2011. In actual this date don't exists. So it must give error.

Comment: @user: this is not what regular expressions are made for... you're trying to use a hammer on a screw.

Comment: There are even more problems: it matches "311apr}2011" because of the `[]` that need to be `()`.

Comment: ^((31(?! (FEB|APR|JUN|SEP|NOV)))|((30|29)(?! FEB))|(29(?= FEB (((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))))|(0?[1-9])|1\d|2[0-8]) (JAN|FEB|MAR|MAY|APR|JUL|JUN|AUG|OCT|SEP|NOV|DEC) ((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$  This is the regular expression which i found which also checks for dates like 30 Feb but its is dd MMM YYYY. I changed it to DD/MMM/YYYY bt don't work for me. Can u please change it to DD/MMM/YYYY format