# Convert JavaScript code to python

Tags: javascript, python

I would like to convert this JavaScript code to python, i have not solide basis in JS.

so i have'nt known how i could translate the code above.

Any help or recommandation please

```
Packer = function(w, h) {
  this.root = { x: 0, y: 0, w: w, h: h };
};

Packer.prototype = {

  fit: function(blocks) {
    var n, node, block;
    for (n = 0; n < blocks.length; n++) {
      block = blocks[n];
      if (node = this.findNode(this.root, block.w, block.h))
        block.fit = this.splitNode(node, block.w, block.h);
    }
  },

  findNode: function(root, w, h) {
    if (root.used)
      return this.findNode(root.right, w, h) || this.findNode(root.down, w, h);
    else if ((w <= root.w) && (h <= root.h))
      return root;
    else
      return null;
  },

  splitNode: function(node, w, h) {
    node.used = true;
    node.down  = { x: node.x,     y: node.y + h, w: node.w,     h: node.h - h };
    node.right = { x: node.x + w, y: node.y,     w: node.w - w, h: h          };
    return node;
  }

}
```

Comment: So either you don't understand the code you posted, in which case how do you know if it's something worth translating. Or you know what the code does, so you shouldn't have a problem writing it in Python.

Comment: Do you also not have solid basis in python? if you have, it should be very easy to convert because JavaScript itself doesn't have that much 'not so easy to understand' language constructs. Read the code, write it to python. As simple as that. Btw, -1 isn't me.

Comment: see also [Conversion from JavaScript to Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346584/conversion-from-javascript-to-python-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is definining an Object called `Packer`, with a constructor accepting `w` and `h` parameters.

It also defines the following methods:

```
fit(blocks)
findNode(root, w, h) 
splitNode(node, w, h)
```

The object has a member variable called `root`, used to hold some status. The rest should be understandable, good luck.

Comment: Good answer while not giving the game away