# Extract/decode Javascript variables from html into python

Tags: javascript, python, html, http, xbmc

I'm trying to extract, with python, some javascript variables from an HTML site:

```
<script>
var nData = new Array();
var Data = "5b7b......";
nData = CallInit(Data);
...
...
</script>
```

I can see the content of "nData" in firebug (DOM Panel) without problem:

```
[Object { height="532",  width="1280",  url="https://example.org...8EDA4F3F5F395B9&key=lh1",  more...}, Object { height="266",  width="640",  url="https://example.org...8EDA4F3F5F395B9&key=lh1",  more...}]
```

The content of nData is an URL.
How can i parse/extract the content of nData to python? 
It's possible?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us a link to the site?

Comment: Do you have influence on the source code in a JS context before moving it to python? For example open webpage, insert a JS-write statement and save it as HTML. So you can write the variable as html first and then parse it via python.

Comment: If not you need kind of javascript runtime environment. May checkout the answers of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346584/conversion-from-javascript-to-python-code and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894946/passing-javascript-variable-to-python.

Comment: @wenzul
no, i'm only trying to extract the url from the site, and use it in a python script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of the python library [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) it should be possible to get a dynamic variable out of executed Javascript code.

I just tried it out with some [small test site](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13991899/test/index.html) and got a Javascript variable named `a` which I use on that page as a python object. I did the following:

1. Install Ghost.py with `pip install Ghost.py`.
2. Install PySide (it's a prerequisite for Ghost.py) with `pip install PySide`.
3. Use the following python code:

   ```
   from ghost import Ghost
   ghost = Ghost()
   ghost.open('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13991899/test/index.html')
   js_variable, _ = ghost.evaluate('a', expect_loading=True)
   print js_variable
   ```

You should be able to get your variable `nData` into the python variable `js_variable` by opening your site with `ghost.open` and then call `ghost.evaluate('nData')`.

Comment: Cool, didn't know ghost. Just mechanize and stuff. For just retrieving the urls you could just look into `CallInit` and build your urls with python with `Data` as a parameter.

Comment: It's possible to do the same but using machanize?

Comment: Please update the ghost library based on its official website's information. I found the ghost class now only have ghost.start() in its newest version, and it is using sessions to manage the crawling.