# How would I translate this JavaScript code to Python code?

Tags: javascript, python, function

Sorry, I know this may be an odd questions, but I made this basic JavaScript program, and I'm not exactly sure what I should look up to know how to translate it to a python program with the same functionality. I know how the code works, but I don't know what the technical term for it is so I am struggling to find out how to do it in python. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

```
var myArray = [];

var myCache = {

    add: function a(x){
        myArray.shift();
        myArray.push(x);
    },

    access: function b(z){
        var zLocation = myArray.indexOf(z);
        var temp1 = myArray.slice(0,zLocation);
        var temp2 = myArray.slice(zLocation+1, myArray.length);
        temp1 = temp1.concat(temp2);
        temp1.push(z);
        myArray = temp1;
    },

    print: function c(){
        console.log("Current array is: " + myArray);
    },

    size: function d(y){
        yArray.length = y;
    }
};

myCache.add(7);
```

---

I don't know how to add the add, access, print, and size functionality to something I create in Python. Thanks!

Comment: You can use Js2Py

Comment: This javascript code contains `myCache`, an object, with functions as values. You can make a class in python with methods that do this. Read about classes and methods and it should become clear how to do this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried much so far, because I am relatively new to Python, but I will try what JacoblRR suggested.

Comment: for generic js2py translation, see also [Conversion from JavaScript to Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346584/conversion-from-javascript-to-python-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As python is an object oriented language, the way to get an object is basically to create a class which acts as the blueprint/prototype for different instantiations of that object. So your code translated to python could look more or less like this:

*(all of you python pros, please forgive me, I'm not =D)*

```py
class MyCache:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # in python the most similar to a javascript array is a list
        # to make it a bit more readable `myArray` is called `_cache` here
        self._cache = []

    def add(self, x):
        # do not try to pop() from an empty list, will throw an error
        if self._cache:
            self._cache.pop(0)

        self._cache.append(x)

    def access(self, z):
        # index() is a bit whimpy in python...
        try:
            i = self._cache.index(z);
            # I think we don't need the .slice() stuff here,
            # can just .pop() at the index in python
            self._cache.pop(i)
            self._cache.append(z)
        except ValueError as err:
            print(err)

    def size(self, y):
        # not sure what you want to do here, initialize the cache with
        # an array/list of a specific length?
        self._cache = [None] * y

    # print is a reserved word in python...
    def status(self):
        print("Current array is: ")
        print(self._cache)

# instantiate the class (e.g. get a cache object)
# and do some stuff with it..
cache = MyCache()
cache.add(7)
cache.status()
cache.add(10)
cache.status()
cache.add(3)
cache.status()
cache.access(3)
cache.status()
```

not sure if this is actually doing what you're expecting it to do, you'll always have only 1 value in the cache because the `add()` method will always remove one...so the `access` method kind of doesn't make sense...but maybe it was just your simplified example code?

Comment: Yeah I only posted a bit of simplified stuff. The add method should shift, so if the size is 3, when you add the first thing gets removed and everything else shifts down 1 to make room for the new addition. What you posted is exactly what I wanted so I can look over it, and learn exactly how to do what I was imagining. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Js2PY](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py). It's written in Python so of course you'd have to have Python but other than that your good. If you want to go the long way then learn Python which would be better because once you have your code in Python you know how to change it.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely think I'll give Js2Py a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Just be aware that the output created by Js2PY is not very readable, so if you actually plan to move your JS codebase to python I would recommend to rewrite it "properly" (e.g. by hand), if you just need to "transpile" it and you will continue to develop in JS, Js2PY is fine!

Comment: `js2py.translate_file('example.js', 'example.py')`